# Alternative to Promise.reject() to handle non-error messages

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I found it pretty comfortable to throw errors with Promise.reject('text reason') to skip all the following .then()'s and give the user the right error message.

Those rejects are not thrown if there is a real error - for example, i use them to skip the thens if a user wants to change is username - if the username is already taken it rejects the promise to instantly give him a return message.

I found this is bad practice, do you have an alternative to my approach?

Short Code example:

```
isBlacklisted
    ? Promise.reject('blacklisted')
    : [more stuff...]

.catch(err => switch(err){
   case 'blacklisted':
     req.flash('error', t('blacklisted'))
})
```

Edit: I don't want to throw a true error, because it would spam the stacktrace.

Edit: My example works properly, but it always throws a msg like: "(node:15764) Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]"

Edit: I managed to turn of the warning with:

```
Promise.config({
  warnings: false,
})
```

but I assume that this is still bad practice. Could you explain me why this is bad practice and what is preferable?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `async/await`? It'll require Node v7 or higher, but it would allow for much better flow of control without having to resort to "shortcuts" like throwing exceptions just to break a promise chain.

Comment: Maybe using : `Promise.reject( new Error('errorMsg') )` fixes the warning. Now in your switch statement you control the error message: `switch(err.message)...`

Comment: @robertklep Could you explain me further where the advantage is?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo This leads to a console.log for the whole error - I already managed to turn the warning off (I will add the code in a sec in the question) but I think it still remains bad practice

Comment: Uh, if you don't want to use exceptions for control flow (and there are good reasons not to do), just use branching with `if` statements?